# Conversion to JApplet -- where did I go wrong?

Tags: java, applet, jframe

PokerFrame (called from a viewer class) worked perfectly, but once I tried to convert it to an applet, it won't load. I don't get any runtime exceptions, just a blank applet space. I won't be able to respond/pick an answer until hours from now, but I'd really appreciate any insights anyone might have....

```
<HTML><head></head>
<body>
<applet code="PokerApplet.class" width="600" height="350"> </applet>
</body>
</HTML>

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PokerApplet extends JApplet {
        public void init() {
            final JApplet myApplet = this;
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    JPanel frame = new PokerFrame();   
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    myApplet.getContentPane().add(frame);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
        }
    }
}


import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

/** A class that displays a poker game in a JFrame. */
public class PokerFrame extends JPanel {
    public static final int HEIGHT = 350;
    public static final int WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 50;
    private static final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 125;

    // the following variables must be kept out as instance variables for scope reasons
    private Deck deck;
    private Hand hand;
    private int[] handCount; // for keeping track of how many hands of each type player had
    private int gamesPlayed;
    private int playerScore;
    private String message; // to Player
    private boolean reviewMode; // determines state of game for conditional in doneBttn listener
    private JLabel scoreLabel;
    private JLabel gamesPlayedLabel;
    private JLabel msgLabel;
    private JLabel cardImg1;
    private JLabel cardImg2;
    private JLabel cardImg3;
    private JLabel cardImg4;
    private JLabel cardImg5;


    /** Creates a new PokerFrame object. */
    public PokerFrame() {

        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        // this.setTitle("Poker");
        gamesPlayed = 0;
        playerScore = 0;
        handCount = new int[10]; // 10 types of hands possible, including empty hand
        message = "<HTML>Thanks for playing poker!"
        + "<br>You will be debited 1 point"
        + "<br>for every new game you start."
        + "<br>Click \"done\" to begin playing.</HTML>";
        reviewMode = true;
        this.add(createOuterPanel());
        deck = new Deck();
        hand = new Hand();
    }

    /** Creates the GUI. */
    private JPanel createOuterPanel() {
        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        outerPanel.add(createControlPanel());
        outerPanel.add(createHandPanel());
        return outerPanel;
    }

    /** Creates the controlPanel */
    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        controlPanel.add(createMessagePanel());
        controlPanel.add(createRightControlPanel());
        return controlPanel;
    }

    /** Creates the message panel */
    private JPanel createMessagePanel() {
        JLabel msgHeaderLabel = new JLabel("<HTML>GAME STATUS:<br></HTML>");
        msgLabel = new JLabel(message);
        JPanel messagePanel = new JPanel();
        messagePanel.add(msgHeaderLabel);
        messagePanel.add(msgLabel);
        return messagePanel;
    }

    /** Creates the right side of the control panel. */
    private JPanel createRightControlPanel() {
        scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: 0");
        gamesPlayedLabel = new JLabel("Games Played: 0");
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        labelPanel.add(scoreLabel);
        labelPanel.add(gamesPlayedLabel);

        JButton doneBttn = new JButton("Done");
        doneBttn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT));

        class DoneListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (reviewMode) {
                    reviewMode = false;
                    startNewHand();
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    reviewMode = true;
                    while (!hand.isFull()) {
                        hand.add(deck.dealCard());
                    }
                    updateCardImgs();
                    score();
                }
            }
        }

        ActionListener doneListener = new DoneListener();
        doneBttn.addActionListener(doneListener);
        JPanel donePanel = new JPanel();
        donePanel.add(doneBttn);

        // stats button!
        JButton statsBttn = new JButton("Statistics");
        statsBttn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT));

        final JPanel myFrame = this;
        class StatsListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // add stats pop window functionality after changing score() method to keep track of that stuff
                double numGames = gamesPlayed;
                String popupText = "<HTML>You've played " + gamesPlayed + " games. This is how your luck has played out:<br>"
                + "<table>"
                + "<tr><td>HAND DESCRIPTION</td>PERCENTAGE</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td>royal flush</td><td>" + getPercentage(0) + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td>straight flush</td><td>" + getPercentage(1)  + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td>four of a kind</td><td>" + getPercentage(2)  + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td>full house</td><td>" + getPercentage(3)  + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td>straight</td><td>" + getPercentage(4)  + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td>four of a kind</td><td>" + getPercentage(5)  + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td>three of a kind</td><td>" + getPercentage(6)  + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td>two pair</td><td>" + getPercentage(7)  + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td>pair of jacks or better</td><td>" + getPercentage(8) + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td>empty hand</td><td>" + getPercentage(9)  + "</td></tr>"
                + "</table></HTML>";

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, popupText, "Statistics", 1);
            }

            private double getPercentage(int x) {
                double numGames = gamesPlayed;
                double percentage = handCount[x] / numGames * 100;
                percentage = Math.round(percentage * 100) / 100;
                return percentage;
            }
        }

        ActionListener statsListener = new StatsListener();
        statsBttn.addActionListener(statsListener);
        JPanel statsPanel = new JPanel();
        statsPanel.add(statsBttn);


        JPanel bttnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        bttnPanel.add(donePanel);
        bttnPanel.add(statsPanel);
        JPanel bottomRightControlPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        bottomRightControlPanel.add(bttnPanel);
        JPanel rightControlPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        rightControlPanel.add(labelPanel);
        rightControlPanel.add(bottomRightControlPanel);
        return rightControlPanel;
    }

    /** Creates the handPanel */
    private JPanel createHandPanel() {
        JPanel handPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, Hand.CARDS_IN_HAND));
        JPanel[] cardPanels = createCardPanels();
        for (JPanel each : cardPanels) {
            handPanel.add(each);
        }
        return handPanel;
    }

    /** Creates the panel to view and modify the hand. */
    private JPanel[] createCardPanels() {
        JPanel[] panelArray = new JPanel[Hand.CARDS_IN_HAND];

        class RejectListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (reviewMode) return;
                // find out which # button triggered the listener
                JButton thisBttn = (JButton) event.getSource();
                String text = thisBttn.getText();
                int cardIndex = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(text.length() - 1));
                hand.reject(cardIndex-1);
                switch (cardIndex) {
                    case 1:
                        cardImg1.setIcon(null);
                        cardImg1.repaint();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        cardImg2.setIcon(null);
                        cardImg2.repaint();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        cardImg3.setIcon(null);
                        cardImg3.repaint();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        cardImg4.setIcon(null);
                        cardImg4.repaint();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        cardImg5.setIcon(null);
                        cardImg5.repaint();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        ActionListener rejectListener = new RejectListener();

        for (int i = 1; i <= Hand.CARDS_IN_HAND; i++) {
            JLabel tempCardImg = new JLabel();
            try {
                tempCardImg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://erikaonearth.com/evergreen/cards/top.jpg")));
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String bttnText = "Reject #" + i;
            JButton rejectBttn = new JButton(bttnText);
            rejectBttn.addActionListener(rejectListener); 
            switch (i) {
                case 1: 
                    cardImg1 = tempCardImg;
                case 2:
                    cardImg2 = tempCardImg;
                case 3: 
                    cardImg3 = tempCardImg;
                case 4: 
                    cardImg4 = tempCardImg;
                case 5: 
                    cardImg5 = tempCardImg;
            }          
            JPanel tempPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            tempPanel.add(tempCardImg, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            tempPanel.add(rejectBttn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            panelArray[i-1] = tempPanel;
        }
        return panelArray;
    }

    /** Clears the hand, debits the score 1 point (buy in),
     * refills and shuffles the deck, and then deals until the hand is full. */
    private void startNewHand() {
        playerScore--;
        gamesPlayed++;
        message = "<HTML>You have been dealt a new hand.<br>Reject cards,\nthen click \"done\"<br>to get new ones and score your hand.";
        hand.clear();
        deck.shuffle();
        while (!hand.isFull()) {
            hand.add(deck.dealCard());
        }
        updateCardImgs();
        updateLabels();
    }

    /** Updates the score and gamesPlayed labels. */
    private void updateLabels() {
        scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + playerScore);
        gamesPlayedLabel.setText("Games played: " + gamesPlayed);
        msgLabel.setText(message);
    }

    /** Updates the card images. */
    private void updateCardImgs() {
        try {
            String host = "http://erikaonearth.com/evergreen/cards/";
            String ext = ".jpg";
            cardImg1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(host + hand.getCardAt(0).toString() + ext)));
            cardImg2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(host + hand.getCardAt(1).toString() + ext)));
            cardImg3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(host + hand.getCardAt(2).toString() + ext)));
            cardImg4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(host + hand.getCardAt(3).toString() + ext)));
            cardImg5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(host + hand.getCardAt(4).toString() + ext)));
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** Fills any open spots in the hand. */
    private void fillHand() {
        while (!hand.isFull()) {
            hand.add(deck.dealCard());
            updateCardImgs();
        }
    }

    /** Scores the hand. 
     * @return a string with message to be displayed to player 
     * (Precondition: hand must be full) */
    private void score() {
        String handScore = hand.score();
        int pointsEarned = 0;
        String article = "a ";
        if (handScore.equals("royal flush")) {
            handCount[0]++;
            pointsEarned = 250;
        }
        else if (handScore.equals("straight flush")) {
            handCount[1]++;
            pointsEarned = 50;
        }
        else if (handScore.equals("four of a kind")) {
            handCount[2]++;
            pointsEarned = 25;
            article = "";
        }
        else if (handScore.equals("full house")) {
            handCount[3]++;
            pointsEarned = 6;
        }
        else if (handScore.equals("flush")) {
            handCount[4]++;
            pointsEarned = 5;
        }
        else if (handScore.equals("straight")) {
            handCount[5]++;
            pointsEarned = 4;
        }
        else if (handScore.equals("three of a kind")) {
            handCount[6]++;
            pointsEarned = 3; article = "";
        }
        else if (handScore.equals("two pair")) {
            handCount[7]++;
            pointsEarned = 2;
            article = "";
        }
        else if (handScore.equals("pair of jacks or better")) {
            handCount[8]++;
            pointsEarned = 1;
        }
        else if (handScore.equals("empty hand")) {
            handCount[9]++;
            article = "an ";
        }
        playerScore = playerScore + pointsEarned;
        message = "<HTML>You had " + article + handScore + ",<br>which earned you " + pointsEarned + " points.<br>Click \"done\" to start a new hand.";
        updateLabels();
    }

}
```

Comment: Enable the Java Console to see what goes wrong.

Comment: I wasn't able to compile your code. You should post the code in [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two weak points in your code.

### First.

If your applet consists of several classes, you should add `codebase` attribute to your `applet` tag, to let it know where to find them.
For example:

```
<applet code="PokerApplet.class" 
        codebase="http://localhost/classes" width="600" height="350"> 
</applet>
```

So, in this example, your `PockerApplet.class, PokerFrame.class` and other used classes 
should be in `classes` folder.

If you don't use `codebase` attribute, then your classes should be in the same folder where your html page with `applet` tag resides.

**Do you consider this?**

### Second.

Your applet `init()` method seems strange. Try to use the following variant:

```
public void init() {
    // Bad idea: the applet is not initialized yet
    // but you already use link to its instance.
    //final JApplet myApplet = this; 

    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                JPanel frame = new PokerFrame();
                //frame.setVisible(true); // You don't need this.
                // You don't need myApplet variable 
                // to call getContentPane() method.
                //myApplet.getContentPane().add(frame);
                getContentPane().add(frame);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
    }
}
```

You can get more help, after you add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

first add the frame then set it to visible. THat usually works